# How can i add multiple insert statements in IF ELSE condition of MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a Stored procedure to insert or update multiple tables based on a value.

Ex:

```
BEGIN
    select count(data) INTO @Update_Flag from tableA WHERE data = 20;
    IF @Update_Flag > 0 THEN
            UPDATE tableA SET data = 10 WHERE data1 = 20;
    ELSE
            INSERT INTO tableA SET  data = 10,data1 = 20;                   
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id;
            INSERT INTO tableB (data, data1, data2) VALUES('0','1','2');
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id1;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with above code.
Here my insert to tableA is working fine, but the next insert statements are not getting executed. Please share some solution.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tableA SET  data = 10,data1 = 20;` this looks incorrect to me.

Comment: @OP: Query on `tableB` sounds good. But, if insertion is failing, what is the error thrown?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen , It's correct. It's just another way of insertion.

Comment: Error is Error Code : 1305
FUNCTION newproject.split does not exist
(0 ms taken)

Comment: @Veena Sujith, How are you calling this function?

Comment: Consider my sp name is sp_int_storedproc. Then i am calling the same "call sp_in_storedproc(comma seperated parameters);"

Comment: is there something like when multiple statements are there in the IF ELSE condition, any block we have to use like paranthesis or curly braces.. etc ????.

Comment: @Veena Sujith , If func is a function then you must call it like SELECT func(argument,...);
If func is a procedure then you must call it like Call func(argument,...);

Comment: yup same way only i m calling and it is working if the if else condition is having single statement each. Now i have to update 2 tables, so i added multiple insert statements in else condition in which first one is executed and second not. so i m doubting we have to use blocks for the same, like normally if () { } else {}. if anyone have any idea of putting the multiple statements in blocks, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this :**
**Your code looks okay.**
May be you've created a function and calling it like a procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_in_storedproc;
    CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_in_storedproc`()
    BEGIN
         select count(data) INTO @Update_Flag from tableA WHERE data = 20;
        IF @Update_Flag > 0 THEN
                UPDATE tableA SET data = 10 WHERE data1 = 20;

        ELSE

                INSERT INTO tableA SET  data = 10,data1 = 20;                   
                SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id;
                INSERT INTO tableB (data, data1, data2) VALUES('0','1','2');
                SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id1;
        END IF;

    END;
```

Call this procedure like :

```
Call sp_in_storedproc();
```

Comment: DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `newproject`.`sp_in_storedproc`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_in_storedproc`()
BEGIN
    select count(data) INTO @Update_Flag from tableA WHERE data = 20;
    IF @Update_Flag > 0 THEN
            UPDATE tableA SET data = 10 WHERE data1 = 20;
    ELSE
            INSERT INTO tableA SET  data = 10,data1 = 20;                   
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id;
            INSERT INTO tableB (data, data1, data2) VALUES('0','1','2');
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id1;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;

Comment: And it is working perfectly with single statement in IF and ELSE Block each

Comment: @Veena Sujith, But I've made it work according to your expectation in my side.

Comment: ohh is it.. :( then i dont know wat is happening from my side... :( let me check again, thank you for yr time.. i will check and update once i find my mistake.

Comment: I was calling another stored procedure for saving the last id information to a log file after each insert which was causing pblm. now after commenting that it is working for me.